# Open Office Calc: How to find a set of values (like any digit) in a string?

Tags: openoffice-calc

Modeled off a solution I found for Excel, I tried the following in Open Office Calc and got an error:

```
=FIND({1,2}, A1)
```

The goal is to find the coordinates in the string at A1 where either the number 1 or 2 occur.  Is there a different syntax to accomplish this in Calc or does one have to approach it in a very different way?  I know I could separately search for 1 and then for 2, so not using the set braces--but if the find_text argument were very large this would get impractical, right?

Comment: I use LibreOffice, which forked off Open Office and is generally pretty similar.  Your formula worked fine in LO Calc.  Over the years, Open Office has had its ups and downs, changing hands, maintenance issues, etc.  I think LibreOffice is currently more robust and stable.  You might just want to try switching.  All of your existing files should be compatible, so there's not much to lose trying it.

Comment: @fixer1234: The error is probably caused only by commas versus semicolons.  When I tested `=FIND({1;2};A1)` in LO Calc 6.0.3.2, it produced the same results as Apache OpenOffice: It finds the first argument (`1`) but ignores all others (`2` in this case).  So it doesn't do what Excel reportedly does.

Comment: @JimK, well darn, if you ain't right.  I didn't look hard enough.  Learned something new.  Thanks.  BTW, just not having a match for the first value produces an error, so the comma / semicolon issue may not even apply (in my case, I have it set to Excel conventions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [regular expression](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions), braces are used to specify the number of times a character is repeated.  My guess is that Excel interprets the argument as an array and checks for each possibility.  However, LibreOffice and Apache OpenOffice only check for the first value.

The following expression seems clearer to me, similar to [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) in Python.

```
=SEARCH("1|2";A1)
```

Or to match any digit:

```
=SEARCH("[0-9]";A1)
```

Documentation: [SEARCH](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function).

Be sure that regular expressions are enabled.  From [Wiki - Regular_Expressions_in_Calc](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc#Regular_expressions_in_Calc_functions):

> Whether or not regular expressions are used is selected on the *Tools - Options - OpenOffice.org Calc - Calculate* dialog.